# Create sorted array from multi-dimensional NSDictionary's sub-dictionary values

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsmutablearray, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have an NSDictionary which contains sub NSDictionaries and I was wondering if it is possible to alphabetically sort the main dictionary by the value of the "name" keys of the sub dictionaries.

```
NSDictionary *student1 = @{@"first_name" : @"Scott", @"last_name" : @"Smith"};
NSDictionary *student2 = @{@"first_name" : @"John", @"last_name" : @"Donalson"};
NSDictionary *student3 = @{@"first_name" : @"Mary", @"last_name" : @"Patricia"};
NSDictionary *student4 = @{@"first_name" : @"Zack", @"last_name" : @"Elliot"};

NSDictionary *students = @{"001": student1, "002": student2, "003": student3, "004": student4};
```

I was hoping to be able to create an array or mutable array that only holds the keys but is sorted depending on the values of certain keys in the sub-dictionaries. Something like this:

last_name_array

```
["002", "004", "003", "001"];
```

first_name_array

```
["002", "003", "001", "004"];
```

Comment: What are you going to do with the result? Why do you have a dictionary with keys 001, 002, ... - why not an array there?

Comment: @Wain Maybe as a student ID (which happen to be 1, 2, 3... in this example)?

Comment: I have a dictionary because the keys are created by 3 character id numbers.  The result is used to populate table view cells.  I want to be able to sort the cells by first or last name.

Comment: I think creating a solid model class in this case would make more sense. Small classes with some responsility makes more sense, than creating a nested dictionary of attributes. Then in the model, you could implement compare: method and use it as you like.

Comment: The multi-dimensional dictionary is created from a parsed JSON file so I have to start with it regardless.

Answer (score 1):

Check out NSDictionary method keysSortedByValueUsingComparator:

You provide a comparator block that works on the values (your student dictionaries) and returns an array of keys.

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/cocoa/reference/foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20000140-SW21